# regex '#/true|1|on|yes/i#' only works for 2nd and 3rd word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to validate a true/false switch in php. User input can be "true", "1", "on", or "yes" - plus it should be case insensitive. Why does my regex only work for "1" and "on"?

test.php:

```
define("REGEXP_TRUE", '#/true|1|on|yes/i#');

echo      preg_match( REGEXP_TRUE, "true" );
echo "\n".preg_match( REGEXP_TRUE, "1" );
echo "\n".preg_match( REGEXP_TRUE, "on" );
echo "\n".preg_match( REGEXP_TRUE, "yes" )."\n";
```

output:

```
[mles@worker]$ ./bin/php test.php 
0
1
1
0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've put double delimiter `#/` and `/i#` by mistake, so the other "delimiter" was then normal part of regex expression, and `/i` case insensitive modifier wasn't working, it was just part of regex

It should be just

```
define("REGEXP_TRUE", '/true|1|on|yes/i');
```